# Finding linear dependance of a set of functions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

where the set $B = \{1+2x+2x^2-x^3,3+2x+x^2+x^3,2x^2+2x^3\}$, how can I show they are linearly independent?  Could I set the three vectors, **u**, **v**, **w**, into a coefficient matrix and find it's determinant?  I'm confused because the vector, **u**, for example, is given in the form $(1+2x+2x^2-x^3)$, and not, $(x_1, 2x_2, 2x_3,-x_4)$.

Comment: Hint: Wronskian

Comment: Wronskian?  We havent covered that process.  Is there a long-form way to do it? (ie. using the definition of a derivative instead of power rule, etc)

Comment: Well, in this instance, since you're dealing with polynomials of the same order, another way to do it would indeed be the way you did it (if I understood it correctly). Did you basically equate the function $1+2x+2x^2+x^3$ to the vector $(1,2,2,1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Row reduce:

$$\mathbf{M} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & 0 \\ 2 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 & 2 \\ -1 & 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Each column has the coefficients of one of the vectors in $B$.

The set will be linearly independent iff the first three rows of $\operatorname{rref}\left({\mathbf M}\right)$ are $\mathbf{I}_3$, the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix:

$$\mathbf{M} \stackrel{?}{\sim} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

(I am not sure what you mean by the determinant of a non-square matrix)

Comment: I ignored the column without $kx^0$ in an attempt to use Wronskian having never heard of it, by mimicking a solved equation.  Whoops.  What do you mean by $I_3$?

Comment: @LetThisNightExplode edited my answer to explain.

Comment: Yes, in this case I got $\mathrm{rref}(M)=I_3$, I augmented $A$ with a$*0*$ vector first to get a _4x4_, such that $M=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &3  &0  &0 \\ 
2 &2  &0  &0 \\ 
2 &1  &2  &0 \\ 
-1 &1 &2  &0 
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @LetThisNightExplode There is no need to augment it. Whether $\mathbf{I}_3$ is in the upper left hand corner, or the upper 3 rows, the result is the same. The point of my answer is that the method to check independence is the same as that to check vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let me know if you want further explanations.